# flask flash message doesn't show up after request sent by javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

In the `index.html` page, I have the following Jinja template code to load the flash messages

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class='alert alert-warning'>
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'> &times; </button>
  {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and a logout text which can be clicked (here Vue.js is used)

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right' v-if='signedIn'>
  <li> <a @click='onLogout'>Logout</a> </li>
</ul>
```

and the related javacript code is

```
onLogout: function(){
  axios.get('/auth/logout')
       .then(response => {
         this.signedIn = false;
       })
       .catch(error => {console.log(error);})
},
```

and the request handler is

```
@auth.route('/logout')
def logout():
    flash('You have logged out.')
    return redirect(url_for('home.index'))
```

Given the above setup, log out works but the flash is not displayed. What is the reason for that and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flash message in your code is *only* displayed when `index.html` template is rendered, i.e. on a page load.

However, you are calling your `/logout` endpoint from AJAX (a simple `XMLHttpRequests` request), and the redirect to `home.index` happens only in AJAX response, not on the site/page-level. And your handler for that response is only setting `this.signedIn = false;`, nothing more.

To fix this, you have two options, either (1) redirect user to index page *after* logout subrequest completes, in your `then` handler; or a more complex (2), return a list of messages that should be "flashed" in AJAX response, and display them manually from JavaScript, replacing (or appending) to the existing messages.